# Calculate the number of different digits in the integer

Tags: arrays, string, boolean

I'm practicing learning Java and I found this exercise online to input a long integer (ex 2827) and then calculate how many different digits there is in the integer (2,8 and 7) = 3 in this case.

I'm considering using a for loop and then with subString, comparing if the number equals each others and they (tutorial) suggest that I should use an array "used" to register which numbers appear, nonetheless

This is what I've got so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class UniqueInteger {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean[] used = new boolean[10];
    int uniqueNbr = 0;

    System.out.print("Input an integer: ");
    String nbrString = String.valueOf(scan.nextLong());

    for (int i = 0; i < nbrString.length(); i++) {
        String bigI = String.valueOf(i);
        if(nbrString.substring(i,(i+1)).equals(bigI)){
            uniqueNbr++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Amount of unique digits: " + uniqueNbr);
}

}
```

My problem is now that this code does not work, and I'm not sure I'm taking the right approach here. I've also not found a reason or purpose to include the boolean array "used".

- What's wrong with my code?
- How do I in a smart way use the boolean array and make my code more efficient?

Comment: Your approach appears viable, though I'd take a different approach myself.  Did you have an actual question?

Comment: You've not explained the problem you're having with the code you posted, or asked a question at all. A valid close reason here is "Off-topic. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers". Can you [edit] to address both of those issues?

Comment: I believe I've addressed those issues now, Ken White. I've asked two questions regarding my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check if the current number in the string has been used (using your boolean array). If it hasn't been used, set used[num] to true and increment uniqueNbr.

import java.util.Scanner;

```
public class UniqueInteger {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean[] used = new boolean[10];
    int uniqueNbr = 0;

    System.out.print("Input an integer: ");
    String nbrString = String.valueOf(scan.nextLong());

    for (int i = 0; i < nbrString.length(); i++) {
        int num = Character.getNumericValue(nbrString.charAt(i));
        if(!used[num]) {
            uniqueNbr++;
            used[num] = true;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Amount of unique digits: " + uniqueNbr);
}

}
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to give me any other output than a zero though. No matter what I input.

Comment: Sorry, I've made a typo. I fixed it! Should work now. For some reason, I always make so many typos on this website, moreso than when I actually code. Weird! (:

Comment: After your edit now, it just calculates the amount of digits in the input. Example (155) becomes '3' instead of '2' since the unique digits are 1 and 5

Comment: That does the trick, thank you. I think I understand it now, just Ive never seen 'Character.getNumericValue(nbrString.charAt(i)' before. But I will read up on that on my own, as I assume it's just a way of comparing/equals. Thanks

Comment: That line of code just converts the character at an index i in the string to an integer. You could also have used `Integer.parseInt(nbrString.substring(i, i+1));`